# Double Dutch jump rope

Tags: word-choice, verbs, colloquialisms

What is the action the two people holding the jump rope in Double Dutch perform on the rope? Twirl, swing, turn, hold, whirl . . .?  What word do you think best describes this action;  and what is the term that is commonly used by the kids who play this?

Comment: Wikipedia uses *turn* and Oxford Dictionary Online uses *swing*.

Comment: Ask the kids who play this?

Comment: It’s ***turning***: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0a3jbQ5Edvo&autoplay=1

Comment: Any or all of the above.

Comment: *"holding the jump rope"* - Doesn't Double Dutch use *two* ropes?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 7 tips to help you **turn** Double Dutch like a pro!  [jumpropesecrets](https://www.jumpropesecrets.com/7-tips-how-to-turn-double-dutch/)

My sense is **turning**.

Answer (score 0):

When we were kids,we used a word  which was Caw. I've never seen it written so don't know if this is how to spell it. 
We would say 'It's your turn to Caw'. I'm Scottish, so I wonder if this is a Scottish word? Does anyone else remember this?
Martha

Comment: I'm a Scot, I also called it "cawing ". Like you never saw it written down

Comment: The Scots word is [ca, caw, or ca'](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/ca_v1) (related to the English word *call*, but with additional meanings including to set something in motion). The Dictionaries of the Scots Language gives under meaning 4 "to swing a skipping-rope": example from the Glasgow Evening Times in 2004: "Their escorts - Sunday school teachers, perhaps, or temperance workers - 'Caw' the ropes for skipping and supervise the races before they distribute the sandwiches."

Comment: [Scottish Words Illustrated](https://stooryduster.co.uk/scottish-word/caw/) even has an example with jumprope.